# Image overflow | HTML | CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have an image gallery where each image is in the form of vertical columns that have some zooming effects when hovered over it. When clicked on, each image should pop for full screen with a caption.

The issue is, with the images of width less than the display device, it's working fine. However for few images (x-pan images), the images keep overflowing horizontally, even after using `overflow: hidden`.

Can someone look into this code and help me understand where its going wrong.

In below code, the first 2 images in the stack are the ones that are overflowing. The rest are all displaying fine.

I tired `overflow: hidden`, set `max-width: 100%` or `max-width: 100vw`.
Nothing worked.

PS: The code might be little messy and there may be lot of redundant or unnecessary tags, please feel free to correct!

```js
var today = new Date();
var bg = document.getElementById("dark-mode");
var words = document.getElementsByClassName("dark-mode-word");

if (today.getHours() > 17 || today.getHours() < 7) {
  console.log("Night time, Dark mode");
  bg.style.backgroundColor = "#34495E";
  for (let word of words) {
    word.style.color = "white";
  }
}

//-----------------------------Image gallery fn's ----------------------
var imagesContainer = document.querySelector('.scrollable-images');
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.scrollable-images img');
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var modalImg = document.getElementById('modalImage');
var captionText = document.getElementById('caption');

var scrollPosition = 0;
var imageIndex = 0;

function openModal(src, alt) {
  modal.style.display = 'block';
  modalImg.src = src;
  captionText.innerHTML = alt;
}

function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}

images.forEach(function(img, index) {
  img.onload = function() {
    updateImagePositions();
  };

  img.onclick = function() {
    openModal(this.src, this.alt);
    imageIndex = index;
  };
});

imagesContainer.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  scrollPosition += e.deltaY;
  scrollPosition = Math.min(imagesContainer.scrollWidth - imagesContainer.clientWidth, Math.max(0, scrollPosition));
  imagesContainer.scrollLeft = scrollPosition;
  imageIndex = Math.round(scrollPosition / images[0].offsetWidth);
  e.preventDefault();
});

imagesContainer.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e) {
  scrollPosition += e.deltaY;
  scrollPosition = Math.min(imagesContainer.scrollWidth - imagesContainer.clientWidth, Math.max(0, scrollPosition));
  imagesContainer.scrollLeft = scrollPosition;
  imageIndex = Math.round(scrollPosition / images[0].offsetWidth);
  e.preventDefault();
});

window.addEventListener('resize', updateImagePositions);

function updateImagePositions() {
  const centerIndex = Math.floor(images.length / 2);
  scrollPosition = centerIndex * images[0].offsetWidth - imagesContainer.offsetWidth / 2;
  scrollPosition = Math.min(imagesContainer.scrollWidth - imagesContainer.clientWidth, Math.max(0, scrollPosition));
  imagesContainer.scrollLeft = scrollPosition;
  imageIndex = centerIndex;
}
updateImagePositions();

const dockContainer = document.querySelector('.scrollable-images');
const dockItems = document.querySelectorAll('.scrollable-images img');
const defaultItemScale = 1;
const hoverItemScale = 1.3;
const defaultMargin = "5px";
const expandMargin = "10px";

const updateDockItems = (hoveredItemIndex) => {
  dockItems.forEach((item, index) => {
    let scale = defaultItemScale;
    let margin = defaultMargin;

    if (index === hoveredItemIndex) {
      scale = hoverItemScale;
      margin = expandMargin;
    }

    item.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
    item.style.margin = `0 ${margin}`;
  });
};
dockItems.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    updateDockItems(index);
  });
});
dockContainer.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  resetDockItems();
});
const resetDockItems = () => {
  dockItems.forEach((item) => {
    item.style.transform = "";
    item.style.margin = "";
  });
};
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 27) {
    closeModal();
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
  /* for Chrome, Safari, and Opera */
}

body {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 55px;
}

.gallery {
  margin-top: 5%;
  padding-top: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.centered-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.image-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#myModal {
  z-index: 101;
}

.scrollable-images {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
  gap: 10px;
  transition: 700ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.02, 0.165, 1);
  transform-origin: center;
}

.scrollable-images::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.scrollable-images img {
  width: 80px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.scrollable-images img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Hubballi', sans-serif;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

.modal-content,
#caption {
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 100%
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .modal-content {
    margin-top: 20%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .modal-content {
    max-width: none;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid gallery" id="gallery">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 dark-mode-word">
      <h1>Through the Lens</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="centered-container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="scrollable-images">
      <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/58f8da6cd1758e3d9a000926/1590933405095-CS76QNG50PO0P07SE711/Hasselblad+Xpan+Cinestill+Portra-7.jpg" alt="Caption here">
      <img src="https://shreyas-phaniraj-ebcf30.netlify.app/gallery/night_city.jpg" alt="Caption here">
      <img src="https://shreyas-phaniraj-ebcf30.netlify.app/gallery/Kollam_beach_1.webp" alt="Caption here">
      <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/58f8da6cd1758e3d9a000926/1590933647894-1QSII5LVB2ACDVC28FVK/Hasselblad+Xpan+Cinestill+Portra-42.jpg?format=1500w" alt="Caption here">
      <img src="https://shreyas-phaniraj-ebcf30.netlify.app/gallery/Clouds_river_atirapalley.webp" alt="Caption here">
      <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/58f8da6cd1758e3d9a000926/1590933228672-9I1VDOZ5Z6E4TMOVIDQO/Hasselblad+Xpan+Cinestill+Portra-2.jpg?format=1500w" alt="Caption here">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="modalImage">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `.modal-content` `max-width: 100%` and remove the `max-width: none` from the one media query.

```js
var today = new Date();
var bg = document.getElementById("dark-mode");
var words = document.getElementsByClassName("dark-mode-word");

if (today.getHours() > 17 || today.getHours() < 7) {
  console.log("Night time, Dark mode");
  bg.style.backgroundColor = "#34495E";
  for (let word of words) {
    word.style.color = "white";
  }
}

//-----------------------------Image gallery fn's ----------------------
var imagesContainer = document.querySelector('.scrollable-images');
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.scrollable-images img');
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var modalImg = document.getElementById('modalImage');
var captionText = document.getElementById('caption');

var scrollPosition = 0;
var imageIndex = 0;

function openModal(src, alt) {
  modal.style.display = 'block';
  modalImg.src = src;
  captionText.innerHTML = alt;
}

function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}

images.forEach(function(img, index) {
  img.onload = function() {
    updateImagePositions();
  };

  img.onclick = function() {
    openModal(this.src, this.alt);
    imageIndex = index;
  };
});

imagesContainer.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  scrollPosition += e.deltaY;
  scrollPosition = Math.min(imagesContainer.scrollWidth - imagesContainer.clientWidth, Math.max(0, scrollPosition));
  imagesContainer.scrollLeft = scrollPosition;
  imageIndex = Math.round(scrollPosition / images[0].offsetWidth);
  e.preventDefault();
});

imagesContainer.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e) {
  scrollPosition += e.deltaY;
  scrollPosition = Math.min(imagesContainer.scrollWidth - imagesContainer.clientWidth, Math.max(0, scrollPosition));
  imagesContainer.scrollLeft = scrollPosition;
  imageIndex = Math.round(scrollPosition / images[0].offsetWidth);
  e.preventDefault();
});

window.addEventListener('resize', updateImagePositions);

function updateImagePositions() {
  const centerIndex = Math.floor(images.length / 2);
  scrollPosition = centerIndex * images[0].offsetWidth - imagesContainer.offsetWidth / 2;
  scrollPosition = Math.min(imagesContainer.scrollWidth - imagesContainer.clientWidth, Math.max(0, scrollPosition));
  imagesContainer.scrollLeft = scrollPosition;
  imageIndex = centerIndex;
}
updateImagePositions();

const dockContainer = document.querySelector('.scrollable-images');
const dockItems = document.querySelectorAll('.scrollable-images img');
const defaultItemScale = 1;
const hoverItemScale = 1.3;
const defaultMargin = "5px";
const expandMargin = "10px";

const updateDockItems = (hoveredItemIndex) => {
  dockItems.forEach((item, index) => {
    let scale = defaultItemScale;
    let margin = defaultMargin;

    if (index === hoveredItemIndex) {
      scale = hoverItemScale;
      margin = expandMargin;
    }

    item.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
    item.style.margin = `0 ${margin}`;
  });
};
dockItems.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    updateDockItems(index);
  });
});
dockContainer.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  resetDockItems();
});
const resetDockItems = () => {
  dockItems.forEach((item) => {
    item.style.transform = "";
    item.style.margin = "";
  });
};
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 27) {
    closeModal();
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
  /* for Chrome, Safari, and Opera */
}

body {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 55px;
}

.gallery {
  margin-top: 5%;
  padding-top: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.centered-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.image-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#myModal {
  z-index: 101;
}

.scrollable-images {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
  gap: 10px;
  transition: 700ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.02, 0.165, 1);
  transform-origin: center;
}

.scrollable-images::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.scrollable-images img {
  width: 80px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.scrollable-images img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Hubballi', sans-serif;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

.modal-content,
#caption {
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0.1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 100%
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .modal-content {
    margin-top: 20%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .modal-content {
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid gallery" id="gallery">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 dark-mode-word">
      <h1>Through the Lens</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="centered-container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="scrollable-images">
      <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/58f8da6cd1758e3d9a000926/1590933405095-CS76QNG50PO0P07SE711/Hasselblad+Xpan+Cinestill+Portra-7.jpg" alt="Caption here">
      <img src="https://shreyas-phaniraj-ebcf30.netlify.app/gallery/night_city.jpg" alt="Caption here">
      <img src="https://shreyas-phaniraj-ebcf30.netlify.app/gallery/Kollam_beach_1.webp" alt="Caption here">
      <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/58f8da6cd1758e3d9a000926/1590933647894-1QSII5LVB2ACDVC28FVK/Hasselblad+Xpan+Cinestill+Portra-42.jpg?format=1500w" alt="Caption here">
      <img src="https://shreyas-phaniraj-ebcf30.netlify.app/gallery/Clouds_river_atirapalley.webp" alt="Caption here">
      <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/58f8da6cd1758e3d9a000926/1590933228672-9I1VDOZ5Z6E4TMOVIDQO/Hasselblad+Xpan+Cinestill+Portra-2.jpg?format=1500w" alt="Caption here">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="modalImage">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Chris Hamilton,
Thank you! 
Looks like `@media (min-width: 769px` was overriding the max-width and causing issue. Now its working as desired!

Answer (score 0):

For large images to fit a container you need to set the container's styling in a specific way...

```
Container_ID.style.backgroundImage='url("")'; // <-- insert image URL here

   Container_ID.style.backgroundPosition='0 0';

   Container_ID.style.backgroundSize='contain';

   Container_ID.style.backgroundRepeat='no-repeat';
```

NB: This styling will also enlarge small images to fit the container.

For the CSS equivalent use...

```
   background-position: 0 0;

   background-size: contain;

   background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

So the magic word is "contain" basically to prevent large images from overflowing.

Comment: Thank you for replying. 
But I do not want to enlarge smaller images, I want the larger image to fit within the device width without losing its aspect ratio.

Also, the `Container_ID.style.backgroundImage='url("")'; ` is something new to me, would appreciate if could describe a bit more on how it can be used in my case.

Comment: No you don't lose aspect ratio... they stretch either height or width... whichever comes first. You should've tried it. Your second question... that's how you specify an image to use as a background for some container (DIV).

Comment: Great! 
Let me try that. 
Thank you!